How to handle `IPoint` removal in NHibernate.Spatial 8 with NetTopologySuite 2.0
I'm currently updating my project from NHibernate.Spatial 5.0.0 to 8.0.0. The update also included upgrading NetTopologySuite from 1.x to 2.0 via NuGet. After the update, I encountered the following issue:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point' to
'GeoAPI.Geometries.IPoint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
missing a cast?)

How can I update my code to handle the removal of IPoint in NetTopologySuite 2.0? What is the correct approach to create and work with points in NHibernate.Spatial 8 using NetTopologySuite 2.0?
Checking the NetTopologySuite documentation and release notes for migration guidance, but no implementation of IPoint exists, so I can’t do anything except implement it by myself.
How can I update my code to handle the removal of IPoint in NetTopologySuite 2.0? What is the correct approach to create and work with points in NHibernate.Spatial 8 using NetTopologySuite 2.0?

Have a look at this wiki article:
https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0-from-1.x#interfaces

I ve already read that… the bad things is geometry created with geoapi cannot be read with WBKWriter to create IUsertype to Point and remove GeoApi

I don't understand that. GeoAPI is/was a set of interfaces implemented by a previous version of NetTopologySuite. The format in which the data has been stored has not changed so whichever spatial backend you use, once you have updated that you should get NetTopologySuite geometries as before.

@FObermaier I tougth the same but with the follow code I have an exception.
